# drag & drop in cocoa app doesn't work with subclass of NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to follow this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZ0mp3-JuzY&index=25&list=PLE83F832121568D36) on drag & drop in Cocoa app.

I am using XCode6, so some methods used in the video are deprecated.

I have make subclass of NSView, named DropView, and I have make my customView identifier to be DropView

Here is the code that I have now:

```
#import "DropView.h"
@implementation DropView

-(id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if(self) {
        [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLPboardType]];
    }
    return self;
}


-(NSDragOperation) draggingEntered:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    if ([NSImage canInitWithPasteboard:[sender draggingPasteboard]] && [sender draggingSourceOperationMask] & NSDragOperationCopy)
    {
        NSLog(@"ENTERED");
        return NSDragOperationCopy;
    }
    NSLog(@"NEVER ENTERED IN DRAGGING ENTERED METHOD");
    return NSDragOperationNone;
}


-(NSDragOperation)draggingUpdated:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSLog(@"DRAGGING");
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}


-(void)draggingEnded:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSLog(@"ENDED!");
}


-(void)draggingExited:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSLog(@"EXITED!");
}


-(BOOL)prepareForDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSLog(@"DID I EVER ENTER PREPARE FOR DRAG OPERATION METHOD?");
    return YES;
}


-(BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    if([NSImage canInitWithPasteboard:[sender draggingPasteboard]])
    {
        NSImage *newImage = [[NSImage alloc ]initWithPasteboard:[sender draggingPasteboard]];
        [self setImage:newImage];
    }
    return YES;
}


-(void)concludeDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

@end
```

I am not getting any error, but It seems that no code is executed. My guess is that frameRect is nil, that is is not initialized, but i have no idea why. Anyone can help me with this problem?

Regards, John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution was that DropView to be subclass of NSBox, instead of NSView, even that I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0):

Is -initWithFrame: called?

If you created your view from IB, register for drag and drop in -initWithCoder: or -awakeFromNib